# Chilkat: Proxy-Authentication getting logged

Tags: logging, proxy, chilkat

We are using Chilkat.Http for downloading files, when a failure is observed Http.LastErrorText is containing Proxy-Authentication which has username and password in BASE64 encoded format. Is there a way to disable or mask this detail? This is a security policy voilation.
Chilkat version -> 9.5.0.78
Please find the logs below:

```
ChilkatLog:

Download:

DllDate: May 6 2019

ChilkatVersion: 9.5.0.78

UnlockPrefix: xyz
Architecture: Little Endian; 64-bit

Language: .NET 4.6 / x64 / VS2017

VerboseLogging: 0

Component successfully unlocked using purchased unlock code.

url: https://example.com?date=20200604

toLocalPath: C:\Program Files\xxxxxxxx\xxxxxxx\1\2\2020-06-04\Archive_Temp.zip

currentWorkingDir: c:\windows\system32\inetsrv

a_httpDownload:

 httpDownloadFile:
localFilePath: C:\Program Files\xxxxxxxxx\xxxxxxxxxx\1\2\2020-06-04\Archive_Temp.zip

  localFileAlreadyExists: 0

  quickHttpRequest:

   httpVerb: GET

   url: https://example.com?date=20200604

   openHttpConnection:

    Opening connection through an HTTP proxy.

    proxyDomain: example.org

    proxyPort: 8000

    httpHostname: example.com

    httpPort: 443

    tls: True

    socket2Connect:

     httpProxyConnect:

      ssl: True

      proxyHostname: example.org

      proxyPort: 8000

      No proxy authentication method specified.

      proxyUsername: xyz_Services

      connectRequest: CONNECT example.com:443 HTTP/1.1

Connection: Keep-Alive

Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive

Host: example.com

      connectResponseHeader: HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy Authentication Required

Proxy-Authenticate: BASIC XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

Cache-Control: no-cache

Pragma: no-cache

Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

Proxy-Connection: close

Connection: close

Content-Length: 1115

      firstLine: HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy Authentication Required

      Proxy authentication is required.

      proxyResponseHeader: HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy Authentication Required

Proxy-Authenticate: BASIC XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Cache-Control: no-cache

Pragma: no-cache

Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

Proxy-Connection: close

Connection: close

Content-Length: 1115

      The server supports the Basic proxy authentication method.

      Re-sending with Basic Authorization header...

      connectRequest: CONNECT example.com:443 HTTP/1.1

Connection: Keep-Alive

Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive

Proxy-Authorization: Basic XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

Host: example.com

      connectResponseHeader: HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established

      firstLine: HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established

      HTTP proxy connect success

     --httpProxyConnect

    --socket2Connect

    HTTPS secure channel established.

   --openHttpConnection

   buildQuickRequest:

    genStartLine:

     startLine: GET xyz/?date=20200604 HTTP/1.1

    --genStartLine

    addCookies:

     Not auto-adding cookies.

     sendCookies: 1

     cookieDir: 

    --addCookies

   --buildQuickRequest

   sendRequestHeader:

    sendHeaderElapsedMs: 0

   --sendRequestHeader

   statusCode: 503

   statusText: 

  --quickHttpRequest

  errResponseBodySize: 18

  errResponseBody: File not present.



 --httpDownloadFile

--a_httpDownload

totalElapsedMs: 500

ContentLength: 0

Failed.

--Download

--ChilkatLog
```

Answer (score 0):

We've updated Chilkat to hide the password for this case in the LastErrorText.  You'll need to contact support@chilkatsoft.com for a new build with the change (for whichever programming language, operating system, etc.  you use).